# How convert None to NULL with Python 2.7 and pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am passing the output from a sql query to again insert the data to ms sql db. If my data is null python / pyodbc is returning None instead of NULL. What is the best way to convert None to NULL when I am calling another query using the same data.
Or a basic string transformation is the only way out ?
Thanks
Shakti

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a parameterized query to perform the insert then you won't have to worry about converting `None` to `NULL` (among other benefits). See my [recent answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419430/2144390) for details.

Answer (score -1):

You could overwrite query function in way that None will be replace with "NULL"