# How to insert null value to int column in MySQL using python 2.7

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7

Trying to insert into a null value to MySql table using python. Below is the code executed

```
sql="""insert into db.table_name (int_column, column2) values (None, 'test')"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```

while running getting below error

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42s22) : Unknown column
>   'None' in 'field list'

Tried this out with reference to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507948/how-can-i-insert-null-data-into-mysql-database-with-python)

Comment: `values (null, 'test')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following, replace your `none` with `null`

```
sql="""insert into db.table_name (int_column, column2) values (null, 'test')"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```