# Can not properly insert NULL value in mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, json, sql-null

I use json format to send the data, here is the fragment of my code which returns an error

```
    def blocks_files(self, db, order_id, op_id, file_ids, images):
        """Creating record in blocks_files table."""
        files_list = []
        keys = list(images.keys())
        for file in file_ids:
            if str(file) in keys:
                new = str()
                for i in range(len(images[str(file)])):
                    new += '%s, ' % str((images[str(file)])[i])
                files_list.append((order_id, op_id, file, new))
            else:
                files_list.append((order_id, op_id, file, None))
        try:
            logging.debug(
                "Inserting data in blocks_files table."
            )
            cursor = db.cursor()
            query = (
                f"INSERT INTO {self.FILES_TABLE}"
                f"(order_id, op_id, file_id, imgs)"
                f"VALUES {(', '.join(map(str, files_list)))};"
            )
            cursor.execute(query)
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            logging.debug(
                "Data inserted successfully!"
            )
        except connector.Error as err:
            logging.error(err)
```

The problem is in `files_list.append((order_id, op_id, file, None))` part. At first seems like everything works fine, but I get `1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'` error in logs. However I expect that it should put NULL in imgs column... I used the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507948/how-can-i-insert-null-data-into-mysql-database-with-python) as inspiration but it's no use. Trying to send "NULL" as a string is not what I want, I need proper SQL NULL value, the difference is on the screenshot
[proper NULL value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02bC7.png)
["NULL" value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iwzf.png)

Comment: Don't construct INSERT statement yourself using str methods like this

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python?) for guidance on how to use variable values with SQL statements. This will get you the `NULL` behaviour that you want.

Comment: @snakecharmerb why does I have "Unknown column 'None'  in 'field list' " error while it should insert NULL in imgs column?  I obviously have no None column and never refer to it in code

Comment: Because SQL assumes that an unquoted character string in the values clause is a column name.

Answer (score 0):

I found one not so elegant solution to my problem by adding one more variable and two `if` statements

```
def blocks_files(self, db, order_id, op_id, file_ids, images):
            """Creating record in blocks_files table."""
            files_list = []
            files_list_no_imgs = []
            keys = list(images.keys())
            for file in file_ids:
                if str(file) in keys:
                    images_list = str()
                    for i in range(len(images[str(file)])):
                        images_list += '%s, ' % str((images[str(file)])[i])
                    files_list.append((order_id, op_id, file, images_list))
                else:
                    files_list_no_imgs.append((order_id, op_id, file))
            try:
                logging.debug(
                    "Inserting data in blocks_files table."
                )
                cursor = db.cursor()
                if files_list:
                    query = (
                        f"INSERT INTO {self.FILES_TABLE}"
                        f"(order_id, op_id, file_id, imgs)"
                        f"VALUES {(', '.join(map(str, files_list)))};"
                    )
                    cursor.execute(query)
                if files_list_no_imgs:
                    query = (
                        f"INSERT INTO {self.FILES_TABLE}"
                        f"(order_id, op_id, file_id)"
                        f"VALUES {(', '.join(map(str, files_list_no_imgs)))};"
                    )
                    cursor.execute(query)
                db.commit()
                cursor.close()
                logging.debug(
                    "Data inserted successfully!"
                )
            except connector.Error as err:
                logging.error(err)
```